# In Fedora 33, (Gnome 3) Desktop Folders dont appear

Tags: fedora, gnome, desktop, icons

I usually use Ubuntu LTS but thought I'd give Fedora 33 (Gnome 3) a try. Works well except when I save, move or copy folders to my desktop, they dont appear there (but show up in a file list of the desktop). Is there a workaround that can make these things appear on my desktop?

Comment: Have you looked on the web? This question is asked often. First search result: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/place-folders-and-files-in-desktop-and-drag-and-drop-option/619   Second: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?312870-Folders-on-Desktop

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one extension (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/) that fits your need.

At the time of writing, that (but most of the all extensions) is compatible with second to last GNOME version, that is 3.38.

If you Fedora system has that version you can easily install the extension and overcome your issue!